# Installing Ubuntu on HDD without a DVD

Tags: installation, usb

I want to install Ubuntu on my second PC.
There is Windows 7 on it, but I can delete it. But my problem is, I want to install Ubuntu on this PC. How can i do that? I have no DVD where I can put in the .iso
So can i install it with Daemontools? Open the .iso with Daemontools and install it? Or how  I can install it from a USB-Stick. I tried it, but my PC (Bios) dont boot with the .iso in it. I hope you guys can help me and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows ?

These should create a bootable USB stick.

Comment: I tried it with Linux Live Usb Creator.

Comment: Have you set your BIOS to boot from USB? What happens when you try to boot?

Comment: @Felix: If you're making the Ubuntu live USB from inside Ubuntu, Ubuntu has its own application for this called _Startup Disk Creator_. There is also a similar cross-platform app called _UNetbootin_ (Windows/Mac/Linux/Ubuntu Software Center).

Answer (score 1):

To install from a USB stick, just:

1. Download [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)
2. Run Rufus and select your USB stick as the device
3. Click Start
4. Once Rufus is done, reboot to BIOS on the computer you wish to install on
5. Change the boot order to USB first
6. Plug in your USB if it is not still plugged in and cold reboot your computer
7. The computer should boot straight to Ubuntu, from which you can install as if from a disk

Comment: My computer can´t boot from a I think so?

Comment: You should be able to tell your computer to boot from the USB drive from BIOS. Just plug in the USB, boot to BIOS, then tell it to boot from the USB first in the boot order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the boot order. You can do this with one of the 'f' buttons or with the 'esc' when you turn on your computer, depending on your device. You have to tell the to try to boot from the USB stick first, and only later your hard drive.